# Unity Ads always mute Android music player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to allow the users of my android unity app to listen to music while they use it. I've ensured the video audio is set to muted in the Unity developer panel, however when testing with Spotify playing, the ads still pause Spotify even though the volume has been muted. I have also ensured the "Mute Other Audio Sources*" option is unticked. Is this a known issue? I can't seem to find anyone else talking about this particular problem online.

This is in Unity 2019.2.9f1

Comment: I don't think unity or any other advertiser can allow to have other audios playing in background while there ad is playing at front. But i would still suggest you to create a thread on unity forum and see what they say.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have been given an answer by the Unity dev team. I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received a response from the Unity Dev team: "We are aware of this bug and will be releasing a fix for it in our next SDK (UnityAds SDK 3.4)."

So if anyone else comes across this, try updating to 3.4 when it is released.